# Why does VS2015 C++ compiler not need to compile functions even when changed?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

We recently upgraded to Visual Studio Pro 2015 and I've started seeing things like this when compiling:

```
2>--- Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Release Win32 ---
2>  MyFile.cpp
2>  Generating code
2>  0 of 631 functions ( 0.0%) were compiled, the rest were copied
    from previous compilation.
2>  0 functions were new in current compilation
2>  0 functions had inline decision re-evaluated but remain unchanged
2>  Finished generating code
2>  MyProject.vcxproj -> Bin\Release\MyProject.exe
2>  MyProject.vcxproj -> Bin\Release\MyProject.pdb (Full PDB)
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Specifically, it's the line stating it doesn't have to compile *any* of my 631 functions. This appears even if I actually *change* the code, which seems a little bizarre.

It also happens no matter how quick I compile after the save and, in fact, even happens if I compile unsaved, and let the IDE save it automatically.

Why is Visual Studio seemingly stating that it's already compiled my code and doesn't need to do so again?

---

For what it's worth, further investigation shows that the executable file *is* being updated when I change the code so now it boils down to: why is VS telling me nothing needs to compile?

Comment: iLTGC I think, new in VS2015.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/11/12/speeding-up-the-incremental-developer-build-scenario/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem but in the community version, what worked for me was re-building the solution.

Build --> Build Solution.

After your build is updated you can run your code and the message that "Visual Studio already compiled your code and doesn't need to do so again" should disappear.